# Voting comments not working

Tags: support, comment, voting, up-votes

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774303/factorial-of-1-e80?noredirect=1#comment1606960_774303) I tried to vote up one of the comments, but it did not show the normal triangle and flag icons when I moused over it. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Edit: It seems as if it is not possible to do this on any post. Is one not allowed to vote on comments to other people's posts?

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: @Oded Internet explorer, not sure which version. And I'm embarrased to ask this, but what exactly do you mean by a JavaScript error?

Comment: Depending on the version of IE and Windows, you would see a yellow triangle with exclamation mark on the status bar (bottom of the window), if there were any.

Comment: Yes, in fact I did.

Comment: If you click the triangle, you should get an error message (or several). But before you do that, can you go to the page and do a hard refresh of the page? (you do that by pressing Ctrl + F5 at the same time) - that may clear out any problems.

Comment: Clicking on it does nothing, but the triangle is also in front of a symbol representing a sheet of paper

Comment: Can you check the version of IE you are using? There should be a Help menu option with an "About..." area that would popup a window telling you the version

Comment: It's IE 8, if that helps in the troubleshooting process?

Comment: To an extent... It is an old version that is not officially supported by Stack Exchange.

Comment: It appears to work in later browsers. I bet that's what happened

Comment: If you're using IE 8, then you're using the internet wrong.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Glib, and hyperbolic. Not particularly helpful either... Some people don't have a choice about what browser to use.

Comment: @Oded: It was supposed to be glib, hyperbolic, not particularly helpful; and to ignore the fact that not everyone has a choice of browser (something I know very well from my previous university).

Comment: Nu, tov. I thought all Metas hated fun, @Asaf

Comment: @Oded: It depends on the type of fun, I suppose. And the general mood of the thread. :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila: ... and the internet is [using you](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2148921/dhs-warns-against-using-internet-explorer-until-bug-is-patched.html).

Comment: IE is only used to download other browsers.